# Does WMI access in .NET required administrative privileges?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I'm writing an application to grab some system information. And I would like to know if the application will require administrative privileges to run. I did some cursory searches for WMI documentation, google and SO.

In everything I have found I haven't noticed any mention of it. I'm taking that to mean that I don't need admin privileges. (Also because I tested it on a WinXP box on a plain user account and it ran fine.)

Anyways .NET, x86 application. Needs to work on XP, and Win 7.

Comment: No, not typically unless it is pointed out in the MSDN documentation for the WMI class.  The *far* more common need for authentication is trying to use WMI to access info on another machine.  It isn't otherwise shy about telling you that you have a priviledge problem, especially in C#.  Kinda like pr0n, you know it when you see the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Like every file, kernel object or any other object requiring security in windows WMI classes, namespaces and instances have an [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list), this defines who can access what. (based on a [SID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier))
connecting to WMI is considered as a WMI namespace access, which also have an [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list). most of the classes and namespaces on WMI do not require an administrative account to connect and read, writes are a different thing. (notice this changes when accessing it remotely, which has a [DCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model) layer on top and has another set of permissions needed, which are administrative unless manually changed)

you can explore the WMI classes and namespaces with wbemtest.exe (C:\windows\system32\wbemtest.exe) or with [wmiexplorer](https://wmie.codeplex.com/) (which has a much nicer GUI), security can be explored with wmimgmt.msc and you can see that \\root\cimv2 (the default namespace) has read access to all authenticated users.

furthermore microsoft has a guide about changing permissions on wmi (assuming you ever need to, usually a bad idea): https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771551(v=ws.11).aspx.